# Ruby & Redis / Skidekiq URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme redis does not accept registry part: bsc_redis:6379 (or bad hostname?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, redis, docker-compose, sidekiq

on my docker server I've got error on sidekiq/redis URL URL sepcification:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config| config.redis =  { url: "redis://bsc_redis:6379", size: 1 } end
```

I get

> URI::InvalidURIError: the scheme redis does not accept registry part:
>   bsc_redis:6379 (or bad hostname?)     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/generic.rb:214:in `initialize'  from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:218:in`new'  from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:218:in `parse'    from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/uri/common.rb:747:in`parse'    from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:86:in
>   `log_info'    from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq/redis_connection.rb:20:in`
>   create'  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq.rb:131:in `redis='
>     from (irb):4:in`block in irb_binding'  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/sidekiq-4.2.9/lib/sidekiq.rb:83:in
>   `configure_client'    from (irb):4    from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in`
>   start'   from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in
>   `start'   from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in`
>   '    from script/rails:6:in `require'    from
>   script/rails:6:in`'

But it works, when I specifiy the IP address, of the *bsc_redis* container:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config| config.redis =  { url: "redis://172.18.0.5:6379", size: 1 } end
=> {:url=>"redis://172.18.0.5:6379", :size=>1}
```

When I `ping bsc_redis` from the rails container, it responses from 172.18.0.5. I cannot find any problem, why this occures.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: Try this instead and see if it helps `redis://bsc_redis:6379/0`

Comment: I've tried before, nothing changed @TarunLalwani

Comment: Then try this `config.redis = { host: "bcs_redis",
   port: 6379,
   db: 0}`

Comment: oh, perfect thank you very much! can you send it as an answer, that I can confirm it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using

```
config.redis = { url: "redis://bsc_redis:6379/0"}
```

or

```
config.redis = { host: "bcs_redis", port: 6379, db: 0}
```

Both are valid but i guess there might some issue because of docker based dns in first one which sidekiq is not handling well

Answer (score 0):

While on docker, only this worked for me

```
config.redis = { host: "bcs_redis", port: 6379, db: 0}
```